# I dont understand this number theory(modular arithmetic) question's solution. Plz help me to understand.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Problem:

Let

$D=d_1d_2d_3d_4d_5d_6d_7d_8d_9$

be a nine-digit positive integer (each digit not necessarily distinct). Consider

$E=e_1e_2e_3e_4e_5e_6e_7e_8e_9$,

another nine-digit positive integer with the property that each digit $e_i$ when substituted for $d_i$ makes the modified D divisible by 7. Let

$F=f_1f_2f_3f_4f_5f_6f_7f_8f_9$ be a third nine-digit positive integer with the same relation to E as E has to D.

Prove that every $d_i - f_i$ is divisible by 7.

Solution:

Any positive integer $D=d_1d_2d_3d_4d_5d_6d_7d_8d_9$ can be expressed $(10^8)d_1+(10^7)d_2+...(10^0)d_9$.

Since 10=3 mod 7, and since it holds that if a=b mod c then $a^n=b^n$ mod c, then D can be expressed much more simply mod 7; that is, $D= 2d_1 +3d_2 +1d_3 -2d_4 -3d_5 -d_6 +2d_7 +3d_8 +d_9$= x mod 7.

Each number in E must make the modified D equal 0 mod 7, so for each $d_i$, $e_i = \frac{x+7k}{c}-d_i$, where c is the coefficient of $d_i$ and k is an element of {-2,-1,0,1,2}. The patient reader should feel free to verify that this makes D = 0 mod 7.

In terms of $d_i$ terms, then, we find each $c_ie_i = x - c_id_i + 7k$.

Then $E= 2e_1 +3e_2 +1e_3 -2e_4 -3e_5 -e_6 +2e_7 +3e_8 +e_9$ mod 7 can be expressed $E= (x-2d_1)+(x-3d_2)+(x-d_3)+...+(x-d_9) = (9x)-D$ mod 7 = (9x)- x = 8x = x mod 7. (Note that the 7s, which do not change the mod value, have been eliminated.)

Each number in F must make the modified E equal 0 mod 7, so for each $e_i$, $f_i = \frac{x+7k_2}{c_i} -e_i = \frac{x+7k_2}{c_i} - (\frac{x+7k_1}{c_i} -d_i)$.

By design and selection of k, all $(f_i)$ are integers, and $d_i - f_i$ is always an integer because it is the difference of two integers.

$d_i - f_i = \frac{7k_2-7k_1}{c_i}$

$c_i$ is a member of the set {1, 2, 3}. Since no $c_i$ divides 7, 7 may be factored and $7\frac{k_2-k_1}{c_i} = d_i - f_i$ is the product of two integers.

Let $A=\frac{k_2-k_1}{c_i}$ then $d_i - f_i =$ 7A mod 7 = 0 mod 7 for all $(d_i,f_i)$, QED.

******I don't understand why ei must be equal to (x+7k)/(c)−di and why k must be an element of that particular set.I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could explain how they obtain the formula regarding ei and why k must be in the set {−2,−1,0,1,2}. This problem is from the Intermediate Modular Aithmetic section of AoPS. Link given here

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Intermediate

Comment: I don't understand why ei must be equal to (x+7k)/(c)−di and why k must be an element of that particular set.I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could explain how they obtain the formula regarding ei and why k must be in the set {−2,−1,0,1,2}. This problem is from the Intermediate Modular Aithmetic section of AoPS. Link given here  https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Intermediate

Comment: A small and perhaps silly observation :  notice that for each $e_i$ you can replace the corresponding $d_i$ in $D$ and hence you get $9$ possible modified $D$'s, whose sum is $8d_1d_2d_3\dots d_9 + e_1e_2e_3 \dots e_9 = 9 \times 7 \times q$, assuming each of the modified $D$'s to be divisible by $7$. (This hint seems more unrelated to the question)

Comment: NB: $d_1d_2d_3\dots d_9$ isn't a product, but the same 9-digit number. So is  $e_1e_2e_3\dots e_9$

Comment: @Spectre   $e_i = \frac{x+7k}{c}-d_i$   how this equaton made? plz explain with a more details . And why k is an element of {-2,-1,0,1,2} , can explain this?

Comment: let me tell you, I am not an expert on that topic, but just felt like posting my opinion on that.

Comment: A better way of understanding that equation would be to work backwards : you see that $c(e_i + d_i) = x + 7k$. Now trace its way of coming. I am not sure how, but that's what I can tell.

Comment: @Spectre what is k in this equation ?

Comment: A better thing to do would be after the first step of expressing in $\mod 7$, substitute each $d_i$ with $e_i$ and observe what happens. For instance, $2d_1+3d_2+1d_3−2d_4−3d_5−d_6+2d_7+3d_8+d_9 \equiv x \pmod{7}$, and you need to replace $d_9$ with $e_9$ and that makes it divisible by $7$. Observe that $D - d_9 \equiv x - d_9 \pmod{7} \implies D - d_9 = 7k_1 + x - d_9$. Also, $D' = 2d_1+3d_2+1d_3−2d_4−3d_5−d_6+2d_7+3d_8+e_9 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$ (not sure if this helps as I have a class to attend at school)

Comment: "what is k in this equation ?" $k = \lfloor \frac{d_i}7 \rfloor$ or $\lfloor \frac{e_i}7 \rfloor$ or $\lfloor \frac{f_i}7 \rfloor$ ?? Not sure... I'm currently doing all of it in my mind so I'll surely be erroneous. Please wait for confirmation.

Comment: better check David K's answer for a clearer solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so now that I have somehow cleared my brain to think this problem over, here's how that equation came:

Observe that $D \equiv x \pmod{7} \implies D = 7k + x$ 
Assume that we want to replace $d_9$ with $e_9$. We see, $D - d_9 + e_9 \equiv 7k + x - d_9 +e_9 \equiv 0\pmod{7} \implies 7k + x - d_9 +e_9  = 7k' \implies 7(k - k') + x - d_9 + e_9 = 0$, which makes be feel that the equation in question is incorrect. Do the same for the other $d_i$'s and $e_i$'s and $f_i$'s and see that it's incorrect when you compare with that equation.

Thanks to @DavidK for mentioning that the equation was incorrect. I doubted why I wasn't getting it while writing this up, so yeah he deserves a shout-out.

Comment: @AbidAfiq actually, you should have accepted David K's answer. He made it more clear to you how to work out the problem as well! :D

Answer (score 2):

The solution is grossly overcomplicated. And in this complexity, the author omitted one or two details that only matter in the unnecessary parts of the proof. And made mistakes, perhaps after becoming confused by the complexity.

---

First, let's do a simple proof.
We start with the fact that the nine-digit representation of $D$ is simply the assertion that
$$ D = 10^8 d_1 + 10^7 d_2 + 10^6 d_2 + 10^5 d_2 + 10^4 d_2 + 10^3 d_2 + 10^2 d_2 + 10^1 d_8 + 10^0 d_9. $$
We can rewrite this as
$$ D = c_1 d_1 + c_2 d_2 + c_3 d_3 + c_4 d_4 + c_5 d_5 + c_6 d_6 + c_7 d_7 + c_8 d_8 + c_9 d_9 $$
with the understanding that each $c_i$ is a known constant coefficient, in fact each $c_i$ is a known power of $10$ with a non-negative integer exponent.
Later it will be important that we know what these coefficients are, but the only known fact about them we will actually need to use is the fact that no $c_i$ is divisible by $7.$

Now we are given another integer $E$ defined by
$$ E = c_1 e_1 + c_2 e_2 + c_3 e_3 + c_4 e_4 + c_5 e_5 + c_6 e_6 + c_7 e_7 + c_8 e_8 + c_9 e_9 $$
and we are given the fact that for any $i,$ if we substitute $e_i$ for $d_i$ in the representation of $D$, the result is divisible by $7.$

What do we know happens when we substitute $e_i$ for $d_i$? The value of the digit in the $i$th place (counting from the left) increases by $e_i - d_i.$
(Note that if $e_i < d_i$ this is a negative increase, which is the same as a decrease by a positive amount. We don't care.)
Since the place value of the substituted digit is $c_i$, the increase in the value of the number is $c_i(e_i - d_i).$
In other words, the new number after the substitution is
$D + c_i(e_i - d_i).$

Remember that we were told the number resulting from the digit swap will be divisible by $7.$ That is,
$$ D + c_i(e_i - d_i) \equiv 0 \pmod 7. $$

A little algebraic manipulation (adding or subtracting the same quantity on both sides, which preserves the equivalence) produces
$$ c_i e_i \equiv c_i d_i - D \pmod 7. \tag1 $$

This is actually nine separate equivalence formulas, one for each place in the numbers. Then we can revisit the formula for $E$ as follows:

\begin{align}
E &= c_1 e_1 + c_2 e_2 + c_3 e_3 + c_4 e_4 + c_5 e_5 + c_6 e_6 + c_7 e_7 + c_8 e_8 + c_9 e_9 \\
 &\equiv (c_1 d_1 - D) + (c_2 d_2 - D) + (c_3 d_4 - D) + (c_4 d_4 - D) + (c_5 d_5 - D) \\
&\qquad + (c_6 d_6 - D) + (c_7 d_7 - D) + (c_8 d_8 - D) + (c_9 d_9 - D) \pmod 7 \\
&= c_1 d_1 + c_2 d_2 + c_3 d_3 + c_4 d_4 + c_5 d_5 + c_6 d_6 + c_7 d_7 + c_8 d_8 + c_9 d_9 - 9D \\
&= D - 9D \\
&= -8D \\
&\equiv -D \pmod 7.
\end{align}

Now with the given fact that
$$ F = c_1 f_1 + c_2 f_2 + c_3 f_3 + c_4 f_4 + c_5 f_5 + c_6 f_6 + c_7 f_7 + c_8 f_8 + c_9 f_9 $$
and the given fact that substituting any $f_i$ for the corresponding digit $e_i$ in the representation of $E$ gives a number divisible by $7,$ we find for each $i$ that
$$ c_i f_i \equiv c_i e_i - E \pmod 7. $$

Using Equation $(1)$ to substitute for $e_i,$
$$ c_i f_i \equiv (c_i d_i - D) - E  \equiv c_i d_i - (D + E) \pmod 7. \tag2$$

But using the fact that $E \equiv -D \pmod 7,$ it follows that
$D + E \equiv 0 \pmod 7$ and therefore Equation $(2)$ simplifies to
$$ c_i f_i \equiv  c_i d_i  \pmod 7, $$
implying that $c_i f_i - c_i d_i = c_i (f_i - d_i)$ is divisible by $7.$

Now the fact that no $c_i$ is divisible by $7$ comes into play:
since $c_i (f_i - d_i)$ is divisible by $7$ but $c_i$ is not,
$f_i - d_i$ must be divisible by $7.$  QED.

---

In the solution on [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Intermediate)
the author goes to some trouble to point out that each of the powers of $10$ is equivalent to some integer in the set $\{-3,-2,-1,1,2,3\}$ modulo $7,$
and therefore if we do all our arithmetic modulo $7$ we can replace the powers of $10$ with integers from this set.
The author also introduces the symbol $x$ as another number equivalent to $D$ modulo $7$. It's hard to see the point of doing this unless the idea was to put some constraint on the value of $x,$ such as $0 \leq x \leq 6,$
which (by the way) the author neglected to do.

Then we're supposed to derive the equation $c_ie_i = x - c_id_i + 7k$ for some integer $k,$ which (as can be seen from Equation $(1)$ above) is **incorrect**.
Then, solving for $k$ in this equation, we would have
$k = \frac17 (c_i(e_i + d_i) - x)$ (from the incorrect equation)
or $k = \frac17 (c_i(e_i - d_i) + x)$ (from a correct equation).
Either way, we have not ruled out cases such as $c_1 = 3,$ $e_i = 9,$
$d_i = 0,$ $x = 1,$ in which case the right-hand side is equal to $4,$
which is not in the desired set.
So I don't know what the author was thinking here.

For that matter I don't know what the author was thinking by claiming that
$c_i \in \{1,2,3\}$ later in the "proof." That claim is contradicted by the representation of $D$ as $2d_1 +3d_2 +1d_3 -2d_4 -3d_5 -d_6 +2d_7 +3d_8 +d_9,$
which has both positive and negative coefficients.

But notice that you don't **need** to show that $k \in \{-2,-1,0,1,2\}.$
In the end it only matters that $k$ is an integer. Therefore $k_1$ and $k_2$ in the final set of equations are integers, and we can deduce that $c_i$ divides $k_2-k_1$
not due to any knowledge of a set of integers to which each $k$ must belong
but simply due to the fact that $c_i$ divides $7(k_2-k_1)$ and does not divide $7,$
and the fact that $7$ is a prime.

In short, the "proof" you read makes many unnecessary claims, some of which are incorrect, and also makes errors in some steps that are essential to the proof.
The particular part of the proof you were asking about has both these flaws: it's convoluted and it's **wrong**, and one or the other of these flaws (or both)
probably accounts for why you had difficulty following it.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that the equation was erroneous. I doubted whether I was getting it right.

Comment: @David K thank you